# Excel Power Query/M - Dynamically Combine a Number of Connections Based on the Number of Pages Available on a Website

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I’ve only started to dip my toes into the world of M (I bought a book and everything whee!), so I’m hoping one of you brilliant people out there can help me :)

I use Power Query to pull data from tables on a website across multiple pages

Lucky for me, the URL for them ends in `“page=1”`, etc.

I have loaded each page as a separate connection (connection only) and have a master sheet that has all of them appended together. Each connection is named `“Page 1”`, `“Page 2”`, etc.

The original code is:

`let
    Source = Table.Combine({#"Page 1", #"Page 2", #"Page 3", #"Page 4", #"Page 5", #"Page 6", #"Page 7", #"Page 8", #"Page 9", #"Page 10", #"Page 11", #"Page 12", #"Page 13"})
in
    Source`

The number of pages that have data varies from time to time and I want to figure out a way to dynamically load only up to the number of pages available

(It turns out this website repeats the last page if you put a page number higher than the max pages, so it’s duplicating them in my master table because I’m loading 30 pages)

So in the example that there's only 8 pages with data, I want it to load:

`let
    Source = Table.Combine({#"Page 1", #"Page 2", #"Page 3", #"Page 4", #"Page 5", #"Page 6", #"Page 7", #"Page 8"})
in
    Source`

Lucky again for me, the `“Page 1 of 8”` is on its own line on the website, so I can easily parse out the “8” with Power Query

A quick search brought up [this solution](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Dynamically-Append-from-Table-of-Tables/td-p/96001)

This seems like a good plan!
I can learn some M!

But I don’t want to use a separate file, so searching more I found a different solution that included using `Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TabelName"]}[Content]`

So I combined it with the above to get:

`Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableName"]}[Content],
    CombineTable = Table.Combine(Source[Column1])
in
    CombineTable`

And I made a table named `TableName` with `‘Page 1’` through `‘Page 30’` down, surrounded it with an `IF` statement so it’ll be blank in that cell if it’s greater than the number of pages

Threw this into the Advanced Editor 
It saw `‘Page 1’`, but couldn’t make a table out of it

I have an inkling there’s an easier way to do this, but my Google-Fu is failing me here. It seems like it should be a really easy solution haha

I’d be eternally thankful if anybody can point me in the direction of an elegant solution :)

-EDIT-
The code for each connection (the URL is an internal business URL, so I've just replaced it with `URL`):

`let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://URL&page=1")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"", type text}, {"Policy number", type text}, {"Creation date and time", type text}, {"Deadline", type text}, {"Case Ref", type text}, {"Lock User", type text}}),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type",2),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Bottom Rows",{{"Creation date and time", type datetime}, {"Deadline", type datetime}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{""})
in
    #"Removed Columns"`

And here's the code to get the page number:

`let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https:URL&page=1")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"", type text}, {"Policy number", type text}, {"Creation date and time", type text}, {"Deadline", type text}, {"Case Ref", type text}, {"Lock User", type text}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",21),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Top Rows",{"Creation date and time"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Creation date and time", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Creation date and time.1", "Creation date and time.2", "Creation date and time.3", "Creation date and time.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Creation date and time.1", type text}, {"Creation date and time.2", Int64.Type}, {"Creation date and time.3", type text}, {"Creation date and time.4", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Creation date and time.4"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns1",{{"Creation date and time.4", "I&W - Retail - Pages"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you are trying at the moment, and what the specific problem is.

Comment: And the code for each page query?

Comment: And finally, the code to identify the "8" from the line "Page 1 of 8" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to test this without access to your actual URL.

But we can consolidate everything into one query by generating a list of pages, querying each page with a function to return the data we want, then combining that data.

```
let
    SourceURL = "https://URL",

    LastPageNumber = (MyURL) =>
        let
            Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(MyURL & "&page=1")),
            WebData = Source{0}[Data],
            #"Filtered Page Text" = Table.SelectRows(WebData, each Text.StartsWith([Creation date and time], "Page ")),
            #"Last Page Number" = try Number.FromText(Text.AfterDelimiter(#"Filtered Page Text"{0}[Creation date and time], " ", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd})) otherwise 8
        in
            #"Last Page Number",

    PageNumbers = List.Numbers(1, LastPageNumber(SourceURL)),
    #"Table from List" = Table.FromList(List.Transform(PageNumbers, each Number.ToText(_)), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Page"}),

    GetWebData = (MyURL, PageNumber) =>
        let
            Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(MyURL & "&page=" & PageNumber)),
            WebData = Source{0}[Data],
            #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(WebData,2),
            #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Bottom Rows",{{"", type text}, {"Policy number", type text}, {"Creation date and time", type datetime}, {"Deadline", type datetime}, {"Case Ref", type text}, {"Lock User", type text}})
        in
            #"Changed Type",

    #"Retrieve Web Data" = Table.AddColumn(#"Table from List", "WebData", each try GetWebData(SourceURL, [Page]) otherwise #table({""},{})),
    #"Combined Web Data" = Table.Combine(#"Retrieve Web Data"[WebData])
in
    #"Combined Web Data"
```

Change the `SourceURL` value as appropriate.

The first function `LastPageNumber` filters the `Creation date and time` column for a value beginning "Page", and extracts the value after the last space - this gives us the 8 from "Page 1 of 8".

Now we can generate a list of numbers from 1 to the last page number. Then the second function `GetWebData` does the retrieval of the web data for each specified page number, and puts those tables returned into a column.

Finally, we combine the web data tables returned using `Table.Combine`

Comment: Holy cow this is even better than I was expecting!
Plugged in my URL and it works like a dream
I'm not sure there is a way I can thank you enough for this; you are truly a lifesaver :D 
I hope to be as skilled as you someday

Comment: Your explanation is excellent and I learned a lot actually; I didn't think of combining all the steps together in one block of code. Now that I know it can be done.... :)